# LAN network, part of the computer can not resolved by name

Tags: windows, networking

I have three computer all connected to a Router(192.168.1.1), here is their information.

```
Computer(WorkGroup) | Operating System        | IP Address    | Network Mask  | Gateway     | IP Info

WinXP(MSHOME)       | Windows XP SP3 x86      | 192.168.1.189 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.1.1 | Local Set

Win7-Ult(WORKGROUP) | Windows7 Ult x86        | 192.168.1.100 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.1.1 | Auto Set

Win7_HB(WORKGROUP)  | Windows7 Home Basic x64 | 192.168.1.188 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.1.1 | Auto Set by a MAC-IP bound on router.
```

These 3 boxes is all set network browsing and file sharing on.
Using IP to get each other, no problem.
But when using computer names:

- Win7-Ult can resolve both WinXP and Win7-HB
- WinXP can resolve Win7-Ult but not Win7-HB
- Win7-HB can resolve Win7-Ult but not WinXP

I wonder why this occurred and how do I solve it (without change router settings).

Comment: When you use computer name with windows machines, you're using netbios (b-node model in this type of setup, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119493/EN-US) - it has nothing to do with router settings. If you want to see why name to ip address mapping is not working properly, the best way to figure out why is to look at the traffic passing between the machines. I'd suggest using windump and/or wireshark.

Comment: Thank MaQleod for point me a right direction. I'm pretty sure it's a name resolving problem. I will need some time to get through the protocol, just wondering which computer is more likely gone wrong.